# <div> blocker for iframe content

Tags: html, iframe, blocking

I am building a page to bring attention to available parts and accessories for a product line that is otherwise burried in my web site. The parts diagrams and check-out feature is always in the same spot on the main portion of my web site, so I have put the part I need to display in an iFrame, limiting what is viewable. However, there is a single part that continues to display, as it is designed to float to the right side of the display window. Since iFrame is now the display window, this floating button is in the way. The web site I am working on is at the following address.

http://www.snoscoot.com/fcaccessories/hondapowerequipment/test.html

Here's a link to a screenshot pointing out what I need to be able to make disappear: http://i1193.photobucket.com/albums/aa354/pbucket10/buttontohide.jpg

The pages that are going to be displayed in that iFrame always have the "div" class of "newsletter". Is there is a way to block certain a certain div "id" or "class" from being displayed within an iFrame? No worries about me stealing content or copyright enfringement, this is my web site (actually owned by the company I work for; I'm their web/code monkey). Any help would be greatly appreciated; I've been wrestling with this one for a couple days now.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript, you could use:

```
function hideID(){
document.getElementById("WhateverIdYouWantToGetRidOf").style.display="none";
}
```